# Moving and renaming hundreds of .jpg files, all named 5003.jpg

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, files, rename

So here's the deal, my girlfriend wants me to transfer all of her photos off from her iPhone onto her laptop (on which we are running Ubuntu 14.04). All of the dedicated programs I tried to do this with did not work, so I just copied the entire DCIM/ folder, which contains all of the pictures on her iPhone. My predicament is that DCIM/ is divided into four folders, which then contain an individual folder for each of her photos. In each of those folders, every picture has the same name, '5003.jpg'.

I want to move and rename (probably with ascending numerical names, e.g. 0001.jpg, 0002.jpg, etc.) all of these files to one folder, say ~/Pictures/iPhone/, using the command line.

So far all i've managed to do is compile a text file of all the individual paths for each file.

Some example path names:

```
/home/jennie/Pictures/DCIM/101APPLE/IMG_1703.JPG/5003.JPG
/home/jennie/Pictures/DCIM/101APPLE/IMG_1431.PNG/5003.JPG
/home/jennie/Pictures/DCIM/101APPLE/IMG_1933.JPG/5003.JPG
/home/jennie/Pictures/DCIM/101APPLE/IMG_1388.JPG/5003.JPG
/home/jennie/Pictures/DCIM/101APPLE/IMG_1954.JPG/5003.JPG
/home/jennie/Pictures/DCIM/101APPLE/IMG_1524.JPG/5003.JPG
/home/jennie/Pictures/DCIM/101APPLE/IMG_1897.PNG/5003.JPG
/home/jennie/Pictures/DCIM/101APPLE/IMG_1582.PNG/5003.JPG
/home/jennie/Pictures/DCIM/101APPLE/IMG_1007.PNG/5003.JPG
/home/jennie/Pictures/DCIM/101APPLE/IMG_1502.JPG/5003.JPG
```

Comment: Are you sure you've copied that path correctly?  It has a *directory* named `IMG_1002.JPG`?  Could you please paste in the output produced on the command line when you run `find ~/Pictures/DCIM -type f -iname \*.jpg | head`?

Comment: /home/jennie/Pictures/DCIM/101APPLE/IMG_1703.JPG/5003.JPG
/home/jennie/Pictures/DCIM/101APPLE/IMG_1431.PNG/5003.JPG
/home/jennie/Pictures/DCIM/101APPLE/IMG_1933.JPG/5003.JPG
/home/jennie/Pictures/DCIM/101APPLE/IMG_1388.JPG/5003.JPG
/home/jennie/Pictures/DCIM/101APPLE/IMG_1954.JPG/5003.JPG
/home/jennie/Pictures/DCIM/101APPLE/IMG_1524.JPG/5003.JPG
/home/jennie/Pictures/DCIM/101APPLE/IMG_1897.PNG/5003.JPG
/home/jennie/Pictures/DCIM/101APPLE/IMG_1582.PNG/5003.JPG
/home/jennie/Pictures/DCIM/101APPLE/IMG_1007.PNG/5003.JPG
/home/jennie/Pictures/DCIM/101APPLE/IMG_1502.JPG/5003.JPG

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sh
#!/bin/bash

appledir="$HOME/Pictures/DCIM/101APPLE"
jpgname="5003.JPG"

for   dir   in "$appledir"/*
do    if    [[ -d "$dir" ]]
      then
          newfile="$appledir/${dir##*/}"
          mv "$dir"/5003.JPG "$newfile.tmp" &&
          rmdir "$dir" &&
          mv "$newfile.tmp" "$newfile"
      fi
done
```

With an initial tree as this:

```sh
$ tree Pictures/
Pictures/
└── DCIM
    └── 101APPLE
        ├── IMG_1002.JPG
        │   └── 5003.JPG
        ├── IMG_1003.JPG
        │   └── 5003.JPG
        └── IMG_1004.JPG
            └── 5003.JPG
```

After executing the script (`./script.sh`), this will be the tree:

```sh
$ tree Pictures/
Pictures/
└── DCIM
    └── 101APPLE
        ├── IMG_1002.JPG
        ├── IMG_1003.JPG
        └── IMG_1004.JPG
```

Edit:

To rename `*.PNG` files back to `*.JPG`, use:

```sh
for     name   in "$HOME/Pictures/DCIM/101APPLE"/*.PNG
do      mv -i "$name" "${name%PNG}JPG"
done
```

Comment: nice answer. its readable and if it didn;t work at first , you could edit as needed. If I was going to use it, I would probably stat the files and possibly use a time stamp from the modified time as the file name. as long as you used an ISO style format it would still sort the same

Comment: @the_velour_fog I didn't want to make the script so complex, but it is easy to change the `newfile=` to any time stamp, if that is required.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your script worked, but there's one problem; some of the directories are named with .PNG as the suffix, although all contain .JPG files, so now I have a bunch of .JPGs named as .PNGs

Comment: @user151768: `for file in *.PNG ; do mv -n "$file" "${file%.PNG}.JPG" ; done`

Comment: I used a `-n` switch, though, so no damage would be done.  That's a safeguard I advise keeping regardless of what directory you do it in.

Comment: @Wildcard Yes, the damage will be done as the file will change name (even if no file will be overwritten).

Comment: @BinaryZebra Sorry, I realize I failed to provide that information before now. I didn't consider that it would be an issue

Comment: @user151768 All is well that ends well. Please do not worry. Enjoy !.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are flexible about the final file names, and these are photos from a modern smartphone, I recommend `exiftool` to automatically organize and rename photos for you:

1. first, make a copy/back up your `~/Pictures/iPhone` so you always have an something to fall back on if needed
2. run the `exiftool` on your command prompt with these options:

```bash
$ exiftool -P -r '-FileName<DateTimeOriginal' -d ~/outdir/%Y-%m-%d/%H/%Y-%m-%d_%H.%M.%S.%%e ~/Pictures/iPhone
```

This should empty your `~/Pictures/iPhone`, re-organizing and renaming them based on the EXIF timestamp data that the iPhone automatically embedded into each photo, into a newly generated `~/outdir` directory. The resulting directory path and image file names will look something like this:

```
 ~/outdir/2016-01-03/10/2016-01-03_10.38.58.jpg
```

### Installing

If you don't have `exiftool`, you can install with

```
$ sudo apt-get install libimage-exiftool-perl
```

### Options

- `'-FileName<DateTimeOriginal'` is literal, part of the argument
- `-d` specifies destination template, you can change for example `~/outdir` to another path of your choice
- currently the `%H/` part is what further creates a per hour sub-directory, within each date directory. If you prefer not to have such per-hour sub-directories, you can just omit the hour part, like this: `~/outdir/%Y-%m-%d/%Y-%m-%d_%H.%M.%S.%%e`
- or if you don't even want per-date directories, just want images directly in `~/outdir`, you can omit the date directory part and just do: `~/outdir/%Y-%m-%d_%H.%M.%S.%%e`

Answer (score 1):

You can use it all in one line:

```
find -name '*.JPG' | awk 'BEGIN{ i=1 }{ printf "mv \"%s\" %04d.jpg\n", $0, i++ }'| bash
```

Use it from /Pictures folder for example. You search for all the JPG files, after that, the awk pipe gets the source and increases it in a 4 digit counter. We send to bash this pipe

Comment: There are hundred files. I believe you really should use xargs for your solution (twice).

Comment: You answer gives the error awk: 1: unexpected character '\'

Comment: Corrected \"%s\"  This was to avoid strange behaviors on names of files like "rm -rf" but i scaped the " character in a wrong way

Answer (score 0):

For example having this

```
cat list-of-files
path1/file1
path2/file1
```

we can do that. Better reset `a` variable every time:

```
a=0; cat list-of-files |  while read -r f; do
  echo mv -v "$f" $((++a)).jpg
done 
mv -v path1/file1 1.jpg
mv -v path2/file1 2.jpg
```

Echo for checking. Delete it for actual removing.